# C# Regex Exception - insufficient hexadecimal digits

Tags: c#, regex, exception

I am trying to write some regex pattern code that will take out certain parts of a text by using groups. Here is the code:

```
    private static string ParseSnippet(string ownitDirectory, string project) 
    {
        Match m = Regex.Match("(" + project + "\\\\.*\\\\)", ownitDirectory, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        return m.Groups[1].Value;
    }
```

The problem I am having is that the pattern I am using causes an exception to occur. This exception does not make any sense to me. I have tested the pattern in plenty of online testers but this did not help the problem.

Would anybody have any suggestions as to what I should do?

EDIT:

Forgot to mention that the exception is "Insufficient hexadecimal digits"

Comment: Please provide an example of what the values of `ownitDirectory` and `project` are.

Comment: Does your "project" variable by any chance contain backslashes? Something like `C:\Users\...`?

Comment: Project contains just a word. ownitDirectory could be something like this:

"n:\\src\\hello\\world\\helloworld.cpp(340,101) : error 0: cannot initialize a parameter of type \\'const Dr::DrawingElement *\\' with 
"

Comment: Actually, I think I know why it comes up with that exception, the ownitDirectory has \\ slashes AFTER error 0:. Still I don't understand what the exception is talking about... Even if I have backslashed, they are just escaping anyway, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk1x0726%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it seems that the parameters for `Regex.Match` are inverted. Have you tried this?

```
Regex.Match(ownitDirectory, "(" + project + "\\\\.*\\\\)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Woops! My bad! That fixed the issue. Though is there an explanation for the Exception? There is not a lot of info on the net about it from what I have looked around.

Comment: I really don't have a clue! Maybe something related to verbatim strings?

Comment: No idea, but if I take into account what other posts on the net say about this issue (even though they are unclear), I would say it has something to do with "\" and escape characters. But that's just an assumption.

Comment: Do you have the value of `project` that is causing the Exception?

Comment: An example is just a string like "ThisIsAProject"

Answer (score 6):

tldr:  You most likely got the error because your input has "\x" or "\u" in it, such as the directory "c:\xenophobe" or "c:\user..."

According to this page (http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html), "\x" is used to indicate Unicode or other language set characters.  For Unicode, both "\x{FFFF}" or "\uFFFF" match a Unicode character with the given hexadecimal index.  Since the name of your folder after the x/u doesn't match the 0-9, a-f pattern of hex numbers and your folder is being used as the regex match, you were getting an error.  Anytime you use your string to be compared as the regex accidentally, you're bound to get regex parsing problems.

Comment: This is to explain the exception.  Carlos Oliveira already solved the problem.